# How to organize this logic? (Create and update based on the radio button selection)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a form that has some radio buttons and below the radio buttons, there are some input fields

[image]

One radio button is static, "Create new registration type", when is clicked the form fields should reset so the user can insert new values in the fields so that he can store a new registration type for the conference.

The other radio buttons are dynamic and correspond to the registration types that exist for a specific conference in the database. When each of these radio buttons is checked I want to show in the form fields the information (name, capacity, etc) of that specific checked registration type so that each registration type can be updated.

**Doubt**

Do you know how to organize this logic? I'm not having success in doing this. The page needs to be refreshed? Or the registration types can be all loaded at once and then use jquery to show each registration type on each radio button selection? Or none?

**Edit registration type form:**

```
<form method="post" class="clearfix">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col col-lg-6">
          <label for="registration_types">Registration Types</label>

          @foreach($registrationType as $rtype)
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="{{$rtype->id}}" value="option1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
              {{$rtype->name}}
            </label>
          </div>
          @endforeach

          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="create_registration_type" checked value="option1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
              Create new registration type
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="registration_type_name">Registration Type Name</label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" value="{{ $rtype->nome }}" name="registration_type_name" id="registration_type_name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="registration_type_capacity">Capacity</label>
        <input type="number" min="1"
               required class="form-control" value="{{ $rtype->capacity }}"
             name="registration_type_capacity" id="registration_type_capacity">
      </div>
      <!-- more registration type info fields -->
      </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Store registration type"/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update registration type"/>
    </form>
```

**RegistrationType controller:**

```
    class RegistrationTypeController extends Controller
    {
        public function edit($id)
        {
            $conference = Conference::find($id);
            $registrationType = RegistrationType::where('conference_id', $id)->get();


            return view('rtypes.edit')->with('conference', $conference)->with('registrationType', $registrationType);
        }
        public function update(Request $request, $id){
            $this->validate($request, [
            'registration_type_name' => 'required|string',
            'registration_type_description' => '',
        ]);

        $conference = Conference::find($id);

        $regType = RegistrationType::find($conference->id);
        $regType->name = $request->registration_type_name;

        $regType->description = $request->registration_type_description;
        ...

        $regType->save();

        Session::flash('success','Registration type updated with success');

        return redirect()->back();
       }

    }
```

**Registration type model**

```
class RegistrationType extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description', 'capacity', 'conference_id'
    ];

    public function confenrence(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
    }
}
```

**JS:**

```
 <script>
        $('#create_registration_type').click(function(){
            $('input[type="text"]').val('');
            $('input[type="number"]').val('');
            $('input[type="submit"]').val('Store');
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: How have you attempted the second part of your problem? Do you have code relating to that?

Comment: add controller code in question description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, the doubt has nothing to do with Laravel or the back-end, it's just a front-end implementation.

If you want to change the default values in the text inputs depending on the selected radio, I can think of 3 different options:

1 - You can refresh the page. Requires less JS but not the best solution, I think.

2 - You can load all the different default values for each radio and keep them in a JS array, give to each radio the corresponding array index as a data value (i.e. data-index="1") and then you can use jQuery to load the values in the input boxes when a radio button is selected.

3 - Use AJAX to load the default values each time a radio is selected. This could be improved by creating a cache of the values you already loaded so you don't do repeated AJAX calls in case the user selected radio A, then radio B and again radio A.

Personally, I think the second option is the best. Unless you have a huge set of radio buttons and loading all the values at once becomes a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The different registration types are already be displaying inside the foreach "@foreach($registrationType as $rtype)...@endforeach". Can you give a example of how to store in a js array? Because Im not finding how to do that interaction with laravel and js. Its necessary to create some controller or use the RegistrationType controller to do that?

Comment: To convert a PHP array into JS you just need to encode it into JSON. You can use PHP's function json_encode() to do that either in your controller or in you blade file (better if you do it in your controller).
So in your controller you can add a `->with('registrationTypeJson', json_encode($registrationType))` in the `return view('rtypes.edit')` line, and then in the JS code in the blade file just `var registrationTypes = {{ $registrationTypeJson }}` as it's already encoded.

Comment: Thanks but like that Im getting an error: Undefined variable: registrationTypeJson (View: /Users/johnw/projects/proj/resources/views/index.blade.php). Do you know why? I just tried to show the registration types like: var registrationTypes = {{ $registrationTypeJson }}
                    alert(registrationTypes);.

Comment: Did you add the `->with('registrationTypeJson', json_encode($registrationType))`?
If Blade can't find that variable you are probably missing that.

Comment: Yes, the edit method has that part:  public function edit($id)
    {
        $conference = Conference::find($id);
        $registrationType = RegistrationType::where('conference_id', $id)->get();

        return view('rtypes.edit')
            ->with('conference', $conference)
            ->with('registrationTypeJson', json_encode($registrationType));
    }

Comment: You should be passing both variables to the Balde view: `registrationType`and `registrationTypeJson` since you need the first for the `@foreach` that creates the radio buttons and th second one for the JS array.

Comment: If you are passing both variables and stil Blase can't read them you may have a typo or soemthing like that. Check your code again.

Comment: Thanks! Now If I have just a "alert("hi")" in the page it alerts but if i have the other alert, no alert works even the "alert("hi")". Like this:

$(function() {
            alert("hi")

            var registrationTypes = {{ $registrationTypeJson }}
            alert(registrationTypes)

        });

Comment: This alert 2 times: $(function() {
            alert("hi")
            var registrationTypes = "hi"
            alert(registrationTypes)
        });